# how to login via capybara DSL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, capybara, rspec-rails

please help solve the problem.

i use gems: 
'capybara',
'pry',
'rspec',
'devise'

i need output to console markup after login emulation.

application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> ..................</head>
<body>
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
      <span>Здравствуйте, <span id="emailUser"><%= current_user.email %></span></span>
      <%= link_to 'Выйти', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
  <% else %>
      <%= link_to 'Войти', new_user_session_path %> или <%= link_to 'Зарегистрироваться', new_user_registration_path %>
  <% end %>  
  <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

spec_helper.rb:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
#require 'rspec/autorun'

require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
include Capybara::DSL
............
..........
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
  ............
  ..........
```

spec/factories/users.rb:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email){ |i| "us#{i}@ad.ad" }
    password 'qwertyui'
    password_confirmation{ |u| u.password }     
  end 
end
```

spec/controllers/messages_controller_spec.rb:

```
it "login via capybara" do
  @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user) 
  visit new_user_session_path

  binding.pry 

  fill_in "user_email", :with => @user.email
  fill_in "user_password", :with => "qwertyui"
  click_button "commitSignIn" 
  visit '/'

  expect(response).to render_template("index")
end
```

after run rspec test console displays follow:

```
kalinin@kalinin ~/rails/resource_test $ rspec spec/controllers
From: /home/kalinin/rails/resource_test/spec/controllers/messages_controller_spec.rb @ line 44 :

    39:   describe "GET #index" do
    40:     it "login via capybara" do
    41:       @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user) 
    42:       visit new_user_session_path
    43: 
 => 44:       binding.pry 
    45: 
    46:       fill_in "user_email", :with => @user.email
    47:       fill_in "user_password", :with => "qwertyui"
    48:       click_button "commitSignIn" 
    49:       visit '/'

[1] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::MessagesController::GETIndex>)> puts page.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
..........
.........
...
```

but after run another rspec test console displays follow:

```
kalinin@kalinin ~/rails/resource_test $ rspec spec/controllers
From: /home/kalinin/rails/resource_test/spec/controllers/messages_controller_spec.rb @ line 48 :

    43: 
    44:       fill_in "user_email", :with => @user.email
    45:       fill_in "user_password", :with => "qwertyui"
    46:       click_button "commitSignIn" 
    47:       visit '/'
 => 48:       binding.pry 
    49: 
    50:       expect(response).to render_template("index")
    51:       #expect(page).to have_selector('#emailUser', :text => @user.email)  
    52:     end
    53: 

[1] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::MessagesController::GETIndex>)> puts page.html

=> nil
```

I do not understand why the command puts page.html displays nil. i need get markup elements

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify content on the page before visiting a new location, otherwise your visit can interrupt the submission of the form triggered by the click_button.

```
click_button "commitSignIn"
expect(page).to have_content("Some text that appears on page when sign in is successful")
# Now you can visit other pages if needed - or follow links on the current page
```

The reason you're seeing nil for the page is most likely because the binding.pry is interrupting before the browser has requested the page you're trying to visit, again why you should be waiting for visible content on the page to appear.

Also - you really shouldn't be using Capybara in controller specs, its for integration/features specs and doesn't work with the response object so you can't do expect(response).to render_template("index") while using Capybara.